# React Typescript hook error - This expression is not callable

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js

im having this issue since i moved the code from React Javascript to React Typescript

I have this simple hook that switch state from on/off (or true false) (code below)
I'm struggling into this since this code were working on Javascript

[Code here to test it](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-typescript-issue-fwhdd?file=/src/Switch.tsx)

So the toggle function has some error but cannot figure it out. Some help would be much appreciated

[image]

```js
// useToggle.tsx
import { useState } from "react";

export const useToggle = (initialMode = false) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(initialMode);
  const toggle = () => setOpen(!open);
  return [open, setOpen, toggle];
};
```

My switch component

```js
// Switch.tsx
import { useToggle } from "./useToggle";

import React from "react";

export const Switch = () => {
  const [open, toggle] = useToggle();
  const [open2, toggle2] = useToggle();
  return (
    <>
      <p>Testing toggle 1: {`${open}`}</p>
      <p>Testing toggle 2: {`${open2}`}</p>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          toggle();
        }}
      >
        Toggle 1
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          toggle2();
        }}
      >
        Toggle 2
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

And now i use my switch component

```js
// App.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { Switch } from "./Switch";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <Switch />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Two changes you need to do to solve the problem

First, to get rid of the error you need to return the value with [`const assertion`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) like

```
return [open, toggle, setOpen] as const;
```

[Here is a Link](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35423) to github issue for the error

and secondly you are using toggle as the second argument while destructing, so you need to return it as the second argument too

[Working DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-typescript-issue-q46vq?file=/src/useToggle.tsx:178-217)

Comment: it works!, thank you so much.
I need to study more about const assertion to fully understand it :)